# jQuery next().val() undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get the next input value after a `<td>` field. I tried something like

`$(this).parent("tr").next("input")` but it didn't work out.

Here the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/F5USY/).

As you can see you need to select an option to parse the input ... I want the delimiter input value of the same row ..

Comment: The value of an `<option>` element is specified in its `value` attribute. The text isn't the value.

Comment: Could you paste all the code in your question here too, please?

Comment: So what's the text then of an input type=text?

Comment: `.parent()` only checks the immediate parent, whereas `.parents()` will check all ancestors. I'm pretty sure that is what you wanted.

Comment: @Blender - If the option element has no value attribute specified, then the text becomes the value. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WECL9/

Comment: @j08691: Huh, I never knew that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `el.parent("td").next().find("input[name=delimiter]").val()`:

```
$("#go").click(function () {
    $('.csv_field').each(function (index, element) {
        el = $(this);
        if (el.val() != "'-- NONE --'") {
            console.log(el.parent("td").next().find("input[name=delimiter]").val());
        }
    });
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/F5USY/7/)**

You're iterating over `.csv_field` which are your select fields. The parent is the `td` so you want `parent()` or `parent("td")` but `parent("tr")` won't work because `parent()` only goes one level up the DOM. Then you want to go to the next cell via `next()` and then get its child via `find("input[name=delimiter]")`. Also note that `el.val() != "'-- NONE --'"` should probably be `el.val() != "-- NONE --"`

Comment: Oh, so I was some kind of misunderstanding parent() ... thanks for the hint